# SVN post-update hook

Tags: svn, hook, phpstorm, post-update

I searched on the web for info about how to implement a post-update hook in my local machine but i didnt found anything! In particular I would like to fire that hook after I update my svn copy from PHPStorm 3.0. I wrote a phing build.xml that will handle a task that i want to be performed after the svn update automatically. Any Idea ? Ty in advance!

P.S: our local machines runs Win7.

Comment: I don't think the plain svn client supports local hooks. (You definitely don't mean a hook on the server?) Tortoise might do IIRC - are you using that or the command line?

Comment: im not using tortoise, just command line svn and yes ofc i dont mean hoook on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Rup has mentioned, you'll need a client that supports client-side hooks (such as Tortoise SVN). Another option - write a script (batch file) that first runs svn update and then does other things you'd like to do in your hook.